# Oracle 10gR2 trigger error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, ora-00923

I have Oracle 10gR2. I am trying to create autoincrement trigger.
Here is the sample:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
/
CREATE TABLE TESTER  (
ID_TESTER INTEGER NOT NULL,
   VAL VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIB_TESTER BEFORE INSERT
ON TESTER FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SELECT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
INTO :NEW.ID_TESTER
FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Trigger creation gives warning:

> warning : ORA-24344: success with
>   compilation error

And when I get error value:

```
select OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO;
/
```

It gives error:

> error : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not
>   found where expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What client are you using to issue these commands?  ORA-24344 is a perculiar error.

In SQL*PLus we can get more information about compilation errors like this:

```
SQL>  show errors
```

As for the ORA-00923 error, that is because in Oracle's version of SQL we *always* have to select from a table.  So you should execute

```
select OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO
from dual
/
```

I'm not sure how much sense that makes, but at least you won't get the error.

---

> "It was Navicat problem"

That doesn't surprise me, as I ran your code against my database and it built without a hitch.

Comment: I'm using Navicat SQL for MAC OS X, latest version

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was Navicat problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for somebody:

If you are using Oracle 10g and OCI driver, ORA-24344 shows when trigger have carriage return sign (\r) in code eg. file was created with Windows end of line style.